# Tenho uma lista e como faço para exibir todos os elementos?

Tags: java

Esse método só me retorna a última posição da lista, as demais ele não mostra. Como faço para exibir todos mesmo?

```
    Agente agente = new Agente();
    List<Agente> lista = getA();

    for(Agente a: lista){
        System.out.println(a.getQuantidade());
    }



    //System.out.println(lista.get(0).getQuantidade());
    }

    public static List<Agente> getA(){
        List<Agente> lista = new ArrayList<Agente>();
        Agente agente = new Agente();
        agente.setQuantidade("2");
        agente.setQuantidade("5");
        agente.setQuantidade("9");
        agente.setQuantidade("7");
        lista.add(agente);
        return lista;

    }
}
```

Assim funciona mas acho que ficou muito feio:

```
public static List<Agente> getA(){
    List<Agente> lista = new ArrayList<Agente>();
    Agente agente;
    agente = new Agente();
    agente.setQuantidade("2");
    lista.add(agente);
    agente = new Agente();
    agente.setQuantidade("5");
    lista.add(agente);
    agente = new Agente();
    agente.setQuantidade("9");
    lista.add(agente);
    agente = new Agente();
    agente.setQuantidade("7");
    lista.add(agente);
    return lista;

}
```

Como posso melhorar isso?

Comment: Quais são os atributos da classe Agente, você precisa de um método que retorne uma lista de Agentes, ou quer imprimir na tela as informações de cada agente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe esse código:

```
public static List<Agente> getA(){
    List<Agente> lista = new ArrayList<Agente>();
    Agente agente = new Agente();
    agente.setQuantidade("2");
    agente.setQuantidade("5");
    agente.setQuantidade("9");
    agente.setQuantidade("7");
    lista.add(agente);
    return lista;

}
```

Ele cria **uma** (e apenas uma) instância de `Agente` e define a quantidade para 2. Depois, ele define para 5 **na mesma instância**. Depois para 9 e para 7. Ele está sempre definindo essa quantidade em uma mesma instância. Assim sendo, apenas o último valor definido é o que vale. A lista resultante só vai ter um único elemento, afinal de contas o método `add` só foi chamado uma vez.

Já desta outra forma, você cria várias instâncias, seta a quantidade de cada uma delas independente das demais e adiciona cada uma delas na lista:

```
public static List<Agente> getA(){
    List<Agente> lista = new ArrayList<Agente>();
    Agente agente;
    agente = new Agente();
    agente.setQuantidade("2");
    lista.add(agente);
    agente = new Agente();
    agente.setQuantidade("5");
    lista.add(agente);
    agente = new Agente();
    agente.setQuantidade("9");
    lista.add(agente);
    agente = new Agente();
    agente.setQuantidade("7");
    lista.add(agente);
    return lista;

}
```

Bem, eu não sei o que é que você quer fazer com essa lista. Mas, uma forma de melhorar esse código aí é a que segue abaixo:

```
public static List<Agente> getA() {
    int[] quantidades = {2, 5, 9, 7};
    List<Agente> lista = new ArrayList<Agente>();
    for (int q : quantidades) {
        Agente agente = new Agente();
        agente.setQuantidade(String.valueOf(q));
        lista.add(agente);
    }
    return lista;
}
```

Entretanto, não sei se esse código te será útil no seu projeto como um todo, uma vez que os dados inseridos são uma sequência de números muito específica e arbitrária. Mas, de qualquer forma, o caminho é esse, é usar um laço `for`.

Comment: Era isso mesmo. Obrigada.